# Proving a function is a monomorphism

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Suppose that H is a group and there is a group homomorphism $f : D_{14} \to H$ with the property that $f(o) \not= eH$ and $f(r) \not= eH$. Show that $f$ is a monomorphism. Where $o$ is rotation  and $r$ is reflection.

So what I think I need to show is that $\mathrm{ker}(f) = eD_{14}$ but I'm not sure if there's another way. My process was to try and eliminate all other elements of $D_{14}$ (dihedral group on heptagon) leaving only the identity element.

I was using $f(o) \not= eH$ so  $f(o)^n$ $ \not= eH^n=eH$ to eliminate them but then I realised that $f(o)^7$ is $f(e)$ and by my logic that shouldn't equal $eH$ so I'm going wrong somewhere. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hint: The order of $o$ and $r$ are prime. What does that tell you about the images generated by them.

Comment: I've been racking my brain but I really don't know =/ is there any other hints you can give to push me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel of $f$ is a *normal* subgroup, and the only normal subgroup of $D_{14}$ that does not contain a rotation is the trivial one.

Comment: I get that the kernel of a map must be a normal subgroup but why does having a rotation exclude it from possibly being a kernel? Also am I right in thinking the only normal subgroups in D14 are the trivial one, the entire group and the group generated by rotation?

Thanks =)

Comment: Yes, you're right, these are the only normal subgroups. And this answers the first question (read the answer again)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help!